# How to do alphabetical sorting on analyzed field in elastic search 5.6?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing alphabetical sorting issue in Elastic Search.

I have a Index: indexlive and a "users" type with following mapping:

```
{
  "liveindex": {
    "mappings": {
      "users": {
        "properties": {
          "user_Confirmed": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "user_DateOfBirth": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "user_Email": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "standard"
          },
          "user_Gender": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "user_Name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "standard"
          },
          "user_Photo": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "user_UserID": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Query is this:

```
{
  "index": "liveindex",
  "type": "users",
  "body": {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "fields": [
          "user_Name"
        ],
        "default_operator": "AND",
        "query": "neel"
      }
    },
    "sort": {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting following results when I run above query:

Neel Chaudhary

ITZ NEEL

neel modi

Neel Yagnik

anu neel

swapna neel

I want the query to return those names first which have "Neel", or "neel" as first word. But as you can see the ITZ NEEL, anu neel is out of the desired order. I have applied sorting by user_Name also but there was no success. 
I know that Elastic search uses lexicographical order as opposed to alphabetical order.

Can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an issue of lexicographical vs alphabetical order. You should create a `keyword` sub-field for your `user_Name` field so that you can later boost the documents with the `neel` prefix:

```
PUT liveindex
{
  "settings": {                            <-- add these settings
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "users": {
      "properties": {
        "user_Confirmed": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "user_DateOfBirth": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "user_Email": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "user_Gender": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "user_Name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "standard",
          "fields": {                     <-- add this sub-field
            "sort": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "lowercase"
            }
          }
        },
        "user_Photo": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "user_UserID": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, index you data and finally use the following query, which will give a slight boost to documents having a `user_Name` field that starts with `neel`:

```
POST liveindex/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "user_Name"
          ],
          "default_operator": "AND",
          "query": "neel"
        }
      },
      "should": {
        "prefix": {
          "user_Name.sort": "neel"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_score": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

You'll get the documents in the following order:

- Neel Yagnik
- neel modi
- Neel Chaudhary
- ITZ NEEL
- anu neel
- swapna neel

Comment: Hi @Val I am using Elastic search for searching in my project from last 2 years but haven't found any good and complete resource to learn ES. It would be great if you can give me some online links or books to read.

Comment: The [definitive guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) is a very good resource (although a bit outdated, but great for leaning the basics and advanced stuff). Also worth looking into Manning's [ES in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/elasticsearch-in-action). Some more links and resources: https://github.com/dzharii/awesome-elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks a lot @Val