# ElasticSearch 6.8 doesn't order by exact matches first

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been searching for this kind of issue for some days and I didn't make it work. I followed steps like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588144/how-to-do-alphabetical-sorting-on-analyzed-field-in-elastic-search-5-6) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116459/elasticsearch-results-sort-order) but no success.

So basically, I have the following data on ElasticSearch:

```
{ title: "Black Dust" },
{ title: "Dust In The Wind" },
{ title: "Gold Dust Woman" },
{ title: "Another One Bites The Dust" }
```

and the problem is that I want to search by "Dust" word and I want the results be ordered like:

```
{ title: "Dust In The Wind" },
{ title: "Black Dust" },
{ title: "Gold Dust Woman" },
{ title: "Another One Bites The Dust" }
```

where "Dust" must appear at the top of the result instead.

Posting the mappings and query would be better than continue explaining the issue itself.

```
    settings: {
      analysis: {
        normalizer: {
          lowercase: {
            type: 'custom',
            filter: ['lowercase']
          }
        }
      }
    },
    mappings: {
      _doc: {
        properties: {
          title: {
            type: 'text',
            analyzer: 'standard',
            fields: {
              raw: {
                type: 'keyword',
                normalizer: 'lowercase'
              },
              fuzzy: {
                type: 'text',
              },
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and my query is:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "title"
          ],
          "default_operator": "AND",
          "query": "dust"
        }
      },
      "should": {
        "prefix": {
          "title.raw": "dust"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Can anyone please help me in this?
Thank you!

**SOLUTION!**

I figured it out and I solved by performing the following query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "prefix": {
                "title.raw": {
                  "value": "dust",
                  "boost": 1000000
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "title": {
                  "query": "dust",
                  "boost": 50000
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "title": {
                  "query": "dust",
                  "boost": 10,
                  "fuzziness": 1
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However, while writing tests, I found a little issue.
So, I'm generating a random `uuid` and adding to database the following:

```
{ title: `${uuid} A` }
{ title: `${uuid} W` }
{ title: `${uuid} Z` }
{ title: `A ${uuid}` }
{ title: `z ${uuid}` }
{ title: `Z ${uuid}` }
```

When I perform the query above looking for the `uuid`, I get:

```
uuid Z
uuid A
uuid W
Z uuid
```

I achieved my first goal that was having the `uuid` on first position, but why Z is before A? (first and second result)

Answer (score 0):

When everything else fails you can use a trivial substring position sort like so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
       ...
      },
      "should": {
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "return doc['title.raw'].value.indexOf('dust')",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc"     <--
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've set the order to `asc` because the lower the substring index, the higher the 'score'.

---

EDIT

We've gotta account for `index == -1` so replace the script above with:

```
"script": "def pos = doc['title.raw'].value.indexOf('dust'); return pos == -1 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : pos"
```

Comment: Good idea, however, `Gold Dust Woman` (index: 5) would appear before `Black Dust` (index: 6)

Comment: Good catch. Maybe another sort entry is needed, this time a trivial asc on the keyword?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found a solution by my own before reading this. However, I found another little issue hahaha. I edited and wrote that issue